# Mysql: how send two parameters in constraction IF()

Tags: mysql, sql

I want set two conditions in query, but query does not work.

```
SELECT IF((I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.100') &&
  (I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.101'), I.num_ip, null) AS num_ip 
FROM company C, computers
WHERE C.id_ip = I.id_ip 
AND C.date_conn = '2015-08-12'
GROUP BY num_ip
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is rather vague.  Try explaining what is going wrong.

Comment: you have 2 where chunks. probably explodes

Comment: explicit joins, use distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be written in other way as well using `CASE` expression like

```
Select case when I.num_ip not in ('100.100.100.100', '100.100.100.101')
then  I.num_ip else null end) as num_ip 
From company C
join computers I on C.id_ip = I.id_ip 
Where C.date_conn = '2015-08-12';
```

** Not sure though why you need a `GROUP BY` here.

Answer (score 1):

IN your query there are multiple issues

1. Condition (I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.100') && (I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.101) wont be true almost all the time since num_ip will have value either 100.100.100.100' or '100.100.100.101'
2. there is one ' missing at end on 101.

please go through "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html" for detailed use of control flows.

3. make sure num_ip is nullable.
4. there are 2 where in query
5. also if you have group by then you should use aggregate functions  COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc. please go through http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm
6. Computer table doesn't have alias used as I

Select if(((I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.100') || (I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.101')), I.num_ip, null) as num_ip 
From company C, computers I
Where C.id_ip = I.id_ip 
and C.date_conn = '2015-08-12' 
--Group by num_ip

Thanks,
Tanmay

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is invalid, syntax highlighting should warn you.

This one should be correct:

```
SELECT IF((I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.100') &&
  (I.num_ip <> '100.100.100.101'), I.num_ip, null) AS num_ip 
FROM company C, computers
WHERE C.id_ip = I.id_ip AND C.date_conn = '2015-08-12'
GROUP BY num_ip
```

Moreover, `computers` table is in `FROM` clause but seems not to be used. Is it normal ?